# OepnGL sampling multitpe textures returns same texture color

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, textures

main.cpp

```
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SOIL/SOIL.h>

typedef struct vertex{
    float x; float y; float z;
    float texX; float texY;
    float texIndex;
} vertex;

void readTextFile(const char* path, std::string* dst);

int main(){
    std::cout << 3 << std::endl;
    
    GLFWwindow* window;
    
    if(!glfwInit())
        return -1;
    
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Geometry Shader Bathing with Texture Atlas", NULL, NULL);
    if(!window){    
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    
    gladLoadGL();
    
    glfwSwapInterval(1);
    glFrontFace(GL_CW);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    
    //create and set vertex buffer
    vertex vertices[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        -1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        
         0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        -1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
         0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        
         0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
        
         1.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    };
    
    GLuint vertexBuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    
    //create vertex shader
    std::string* shaderSource = new std::string();
    
    readTextFile("shader/vertexShader.glsl", shaderSource);
    const char* vertexShaderSourcePtr = shaderSource->c_str();
    
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSourcePtr, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    GLint status;
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    if(status == GL_FALSE){
        char buffer[512];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, buffer);
        std::cout << "vertexShader FAIL : " << std::endl <<
            shaderSource <<std::endl 
            << buffer << std::endl;
    }else{
        std::cout << "vertexShader compile success!" << std::endl;
    }
    
    //create fragment shader
    readTextFile("shader/fragmentShader.glsl", shaderSource);
    const char* fragmentShaderSourcePtr = shaderSource->c_str();
    
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSourcePtr, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
    
    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    if(status == GL_FALSE){
        char buffer[512];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, buffer);
        std::cout << "fragmentShader FAIL : " << std::endl <<
            shaderSource <<std::endl 
            << buffer << std::endl;
    }else{
        std::cout << "fragmentShader compile success!" << std::endl;
    }
    
    delete shaderSource;
    
    //create and set program
    GLint program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);
    
    glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "inPos");
    glBindAttribLocation(program, 1, "inTex");
    glBindAttribLocation(program, 2, "inTexIndex");
    
    glLinkProgram(program);
    //set frameBuffer(renderTarget) index and fragmentShader output name
    glBindFragDataLocation(program, 0, "outColor"); 
    glUseProgram(program);
    
    //create and set texture
    int width = 384;
    int height = 384;
    unsigned char* textureRawData0 = SOIL_load_image("resource/character/test0.png", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);
    unsigned char* textureRawData1 = SOIL_load_image("resource/character/test1.png", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_RGBA);
    
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program, "texture0"), 0);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program, "texture1"), 1);
    
    GLuint texture1;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture1);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureRawData0);
    SOIL_free_image_data(textureRawData0);
    
    std:: cout << "texture0: " << glGetUniformLocation(program, "texture0") << std::endl;
    
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    
    GLuint texture2;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture2);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureRawData1);
    SOIL_free_image_data(textureRawData1);

    std:: cout << "texture1: " << glGetUniformLocation(program, "texture1")  << std::endl;
    
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    
    
    //input layout : vertex Attribute
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    
    
    glLinkProgram(program);
    
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), (void*)(5 * sizeof(float)));
    
    
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
        int width, height;
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12);
        
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

void readTextFile(const char* path, std::string* dst){
    std::ifstream f;
    f.open(path);
    
    if(f.is_open()){
        std::string buff;
        dst->clear();
        while(!f.eof()){
            std::getline(f, buff);
            dst->append(buff);
            dst->push_back('\n');
        }
        
        dst->push_back('\0');
        
        f.close();
    }else{
        std::cout << "파일 열기 실패 : " << *dst << std::endl;
    }
}
```

ps

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 outTex;
in float outTexIndex;
out vec4 outColor;

uniform sampler2D texture0;
uniform sampler2D texture1;

void main(){
    if(outTexIndex == 0.0f){
        outColor = texture(texture0, outTex);
    }

    else if(outTexIndex == 1.0f){
        outColor = texture(texture1, outTex) + vec4(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    }
}
```

The input layout(vertex attribute) works fine.
TexIndex is transferred correctly. 1.0f and 0.0f

But the problem is

//fragment shader

`texture(texture0, outTex);`

`texture(texture1, outTex);`

both returns same texture color but it is actually different texture from test1.png and test2.png. what is the problem with my code?

++
I tried below fragment shader following the answer of @Rabbid76

```
#version 330 core

in vec2 outTex;
in float outTexIndex;
out vec4 outColor;

uniform sampler2D texture0;
uniform sampler2D texture1;

void main()
{
    vec4 c1 = texture(texture0, outTex) + vec4(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    vec4 c2 = texture(texture1, outTex) + vec4(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    outColor = mix(c1, c2, outTexIndex); 
}
```

Color applied but still sampling from same the texture. looks like somehow glActiveTexture(i); doesn't work.

ps. test1.png and test2.png is completely different picture. above screenshot is test1.png

++ when I changed

```
glGenTexture(1, &texture0);
glGenTexture(1, &texture1);
```

to

```
glGenTexture(0, &texture0);
glGenTexture(0, &texture1);
```

then sampler2D texture0 and sampler2D texture1 both sample from texture1 test1.png (not form texture0 which is test0.png)

what is happening?

++

vs

```
#version 330

in vec3 inPos;
in vec2 inTex;
in float inTexIndex;

out vec2 outTex;
out float outTexIndex;

void main(){
    outTex = inTex;
    gl_position = vec4(inPos, 1.0f);
    outTexIndex = inTexIndex;
}
```

Comment: `glGenTexture(0, &texture0);` glGenTexture(0, &texture1); doesn't make any sense. The values of `texture0` and `texture1` won't be changed at all. Most likely both variables have the same value. At the end there is just 1 texture because the 1st texture object is "overwritten" by the 2nd texture object.

Comment: What does the vertex shader do? What is the type of `inTexIndex`?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I uploaded vertex shader code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought if I have a compiled example of multiple textures that working no problem, then I can find the problem of my code changing my code line to line comparing with the example. So I found this one.

[tutorial](https://open.gl/textures)

[example code](https://open.gl/content/code/c3_multitexture.txt)

It was SDL based. So I changed initialization code and loop to glfw. And It worked fine on my environment.

Even after I changed my code's texture loading part completely same with the example, the problem wasn't solved. So it must be other part that makes the problem. Finally, I found this.

```
//input layout : vertex Attribute
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

//*****here!*****
//glLinkProgram(program);    
    
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(vertex), (void*)(5 * sizeof(float)));
```

After I just add two characters "//", result was shown as I intended.
I'm not sure about the reason that one line of code makes problem.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I added a comment in front of the line `glLinkProgram(program);` to disable the line. I'm not sure about how it works but the result was shown as I intended. I think some how it broke the texture unit things.

Answer (score 0):

Since the condition `if(outTexIndex == 0.0f)` depends on a fragment shader input, that may cause undefined behavior.

See (most recent) [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification - 8.9. Texture Functions](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html)

> [...] Some texture functions (non-“Lod” and non-“Grad” versions) may require implicit derivatives. Implicit derivatives are undefined within non-uniform control flow and for non-fragment shader texture fetches. [...]

respectively [Non-uniform flow control](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Non-uniform_flow_control).

Lookup both textures and [`mix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml) the colors to solve the issue:

```c
#version 330 core

in vec2 outTex;
in float outTexIndex;
out vec4 outColor;

uniform sampler2D texture0;
uniform sampler2D texture1;

void main()
{
    vec4 c1 = texture(texture0, outTex);
    vec4 c2 = texture(texture1, outTex) + vec4(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    outColor = mix(c1, c2, outTexIndex); 
}
```